# Custom Fonts Don't Work when using them as a static resource (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: xml, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin (pretty much explicitly on an Android emulator to run the app). I have imported 2 fonts I want to use in my app. Everything works fine when using the fonts in the specific tags but when I use the font as a part of a static resource, it just uses the default font.

```
<Label Text="lorem ipsum" FontFamily="CustomFont1" /> //This Works
<Label Text="lorem ipsum" Style="{StaticResource StyleWithFont}" /> //This doesn't work
```

the second line shows the text with the default font. Not a lot of info on this stuff on the internet :/

EDIT:
this is how i have my style in the app.xaml page (Staatliches is the custom font i have imported which works when i consume it like in the first example but not when i consume it through a style)

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Blue_Btn">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#030D30" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Font" Value="Staatliches" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="9" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None" />
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="40" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Can you show the code of this  Style="{StaticResource StyleWithFont}"

Comment: As BasH said, we need to see how the StaticResource is setup in the ResourceDictionary

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to read how the styles are defined and how to use them [Xamarin Styling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/).

In summary you can define your styles on a page you need them and the styles are them only accessible from this page, Or you define them globally then you styles are from every page accessible.

**Example on same page:**

*style definition:*

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LabelWithCustomFont1" >
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="CustomFont1"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

*Consuming the style:*

```
<Label Text="lorem ipsum" Style="{StaticResource LabelWithCustomFont1}" />
```

**Example on global:**

*Style definition on App.xaml:*

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="GlobalLabelWithCustomFont1">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="CustomFont1"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

You can consume the style from every page.

Comment: Thats how i have it right now and it doesnt appear with the font

Answer (score 0):

Okay nevermind, I realized that I used the wrong keyword to reference the font - I wrote Font instead of FontFamily

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).